# Error in loading maven artifacts with eclipse juno and java 8 installed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have installed Eclipse Juno and integrated Maven, but when I try to create a Maven project, it is showing the error, `Retrieving archetypes: GC overhead limit exceeded`.  Before I had Juno installed, I Kepler installed and used the same Maven and it worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have lost your JVM tuning around heap size with new installation

edit your `eclipse.ini`

and modify the values below to change [Java's initial & maximum memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/3357935)

```
-vmargs
-Xms512mm
-Xmx2g
```

Provide appropriate values as per your environment.

Comment: increased heap memory to 2GB but still am facing the same issue@jigar

Comment: but my old projects which are there in my eclipse IDE shows red color cross mark on top of project.but project running fine.why it is showing as error?

Comment: `windows > show view > problems` will show your all the error messages

Comment: @JigarJoshi Thanks for your solution... I resolved this issue with your answer :)

Comment: @JigarJoshi: I am using Eclipse Neon 3 in Windows, -Xms512mm not work: "Cannot create Java virtual machine", when I change to -Xms512m, its worked, is it a type or have some mean?

Comment: One important note is to fully restart Eclipse. If you use the `Restart` option from the main menu, the memory settings seem to be preserved.